# Should i use different class for every page with Page Object Pattern?

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to make automation for my email address (gmail) and i implemented `Page Object Pattern` using [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/software-engineering-best-practices/getting-started-with-page-object-pattern-for-your-selenium-tests) tutorial.

So i wonder if i need to create different `class` for every `page` for example for `Login page`, `Inbox page` etc.

Or maybe its better to use one `class` `GmailMainPage` and from this `class` implement all the actions that user can do ?

Comment: Of course yes it's shown on the first image illustration

Comment: So in case of GmailLogInPage i need also GmailLogInPageElementMap and GmailLogInPageValidator ?? avery page will be 3 classes ?

Comment: If I understand all correctly by this pattern every html page must have one object which will contain all actions that user can do on it.

Comment: There is no mention of an ElementMap or PageValidator in the linked tutorial. You should probably spend some more time reading the article and playing with the example code.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create one class per page, which also happens to be how the pattern is normally implemented.

If you use only one class, it will become very big very quickly. You will also have methods on different pages with similar names which will get confusing and force you to suffix all methods on the single page object with the "real" page name (ie:  SaveUserPreferences, SaveEmailForwarding preferences, etc.).

I create one class per page unless:

1. The page is really big and I can split it into distinct logical units.
2. One part of the page is repeated on many pages and will be reused across the test suite.

Comment: You mean 3 classes per page ?

Comment: @user979033 I've upadted my answer but in your specific case, no I would create only one class.

Answer (score 0):

> But as mentioned above, there is not necessarily a one-to-one mapping between a complete HTML page and a page object. A page object should represent a meaningful contextual part of the page.

Really you should almost not think about page objects as specific pages, but shared functionality for a specific part of your application.  The goal is to have the least amount of reused code as possible. One of the ways you can do that is by turning each page into its own class.  That may work for normal websites, but things like gmail you can further break down features into specific classes.

For instance, Starred/Important/Sent Mail all those pages share a lot of the same functionality.  If you go by one page per class rule then each of those would have its own class.  However, in reality those three pages share almost everything except the content in the list of emails.  So you don't end up coding everything 3 times over, the better option is instead extend something other then pageobject.  You could have an emailListObject that has all the functions of those three pages, then emailListObject could extend PageObject.  The only difference in each of those three pages may only be which of them gets highlighted in red when clicked.

Comment: i was thinking split Gmail for instance into several classes, i am not talking about Starred/Important/Sent Mail  but GmailLoginPage, GmailInboxPage, GmailComposeMailPage and GmailReadEmailPage, all those are quite different, dont you think ?

Comment: Mine was just an example, but yes that sounds like a good start. Remember you can also add things to your pageobject class that are shared between your pages such as that top nav bar in gmail.

Comment: By saying add things what do you mean ? just add this object again ?

Comment: Sorry by things I meant methods, like clickGoogleAccount() that is always in the upper right hand side for all pages so by putting it in the pageobject class all your pages inherit that method.  Then if it ever changes you don't have to edit 20 different logout methods.